# SMTP Mail failure error when adding attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I can't send mail with attachments, although it works fine without the attachment.I want to attach a CSV file. I keep on getting the exception "Failure to send mail"

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);        
  emailClient.EnableSsl = true;
  emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
  emailClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(port);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(ms);
  st.Write("dsadasdasd,dasdasdas");
  st.Flush();
  st.Dispose();
  System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(sender, receiver,subject,emailBody);    
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, "text/CSV"); 
 message.Attachments.Add(attach);
  emailClient.Send(message);
```

Any pointers would

Comment: first no exception is given to us to tell us what is the problem. The code is correct, probably the problem is in **ms** ! Also what is ms ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the attachment file size..basically IIS allows 4MB only by default...
some times it may cause the mail sending.....
First Check with file size less than 4MB.. If it was send Successfully, then the problem is file size..
To solve add this in your webconfig

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="524288" executionTimeout="120000" />
```

and inside

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
...........................................................................
......................................
</system.webServer>
```